# Understanding how to fetch a Cloud Function with CORS

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, cors, google-cloud-functions, fetch

I have deployed the Python Cloud Function shown in the [documentation of Google](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http).

```
def cors_enabled_function(request):
    # For more information about CORS and CORS preflight requests, see
    # https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request
    # for more information.

    # Set CORS headers for the preflight request
    if request.method == 'OPTIONS':
        # Allows GET requests from any origin with the Content-Type
        # header and caches preflight response for an 3600s
        headers = {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
            'Access-Control-Max-Age': '3600'
        }

        return ('', 204, headers)

    # Set CORS headers for the main request
    headers = {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    }

    return ('Hello World!', 200, headers)
```

When I fetch the endpoint from the browser like this:

```
fetch('https://this-is-a-secret.cloudfunctions.net/cors-enabled-function',
{method: 'GET'}).then(response => console.log(response))
```

I get the following `Response` object:

```
Response {type: "cors", url: "https://this-is-a-secret.cloudfunctions.net/cors-enabled-function", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}
type: "cors"
url: "https://this-is-a-secret.cloudfunctions.net/cors-enabled-function"
redirected: false
status: 200
ok: true
statusText: ""
headers: Headers {}
body: (...)
bodyUsed: false
__proto__: Response
```

If I do the same but with a `POST` method I get exactly the same result. If I change the method to `PUT` then it throws an error, which is expected because I am only allowing the `GET` method.

My question is the following:
**Why I am not shown the same error when I fetch with `POST`?**

Answer (score 0):

If you set :

```
if request.method == 'GET':
```

1.Running `curl -X POST or PUT url and check 'gcloud functions logs read' will see:

```
 Function execution took 9 ms, finished with status code: 200
```

If you check the `curl -v` you will see that the headers:

```
 access-control-allow-origin: *
```

2.Running 'curl -X GET url' and check 'gcloud functions logs read' will see:

```
 Function execution took 13 ms, finished with status code: 204
```

If you check the `curl -v` you will see that the headers:

```
 < access-control-allow-headers: Content-Type
 < access-control-allow-methods: GET
 < access-control-allow-origin: *
 < access-control-max-age: 3600
```

Therefore I do not understand what do you mean by getting exactly the same result when running a GET and a POST.